# Getting error if I use docker build-arg in jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need to use host ssh key inside docker , for this purpose i have build docker like

```
docker build -t example --build-arg ssh_prv_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"  -f dockerfile-dev .
```

if we use direct docker command it is working fine , but if I use inside the jenkins pipe-line script getting below error

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 92: expecting '}', found 'ssh_prv_key' @ line 92, column 116.
   ev:${GIT_COMMIT} "--build-arg ssh_prv_ke
```

Below step i have used in jenkins pipe-line

```
 sh "docker build -t ${service_name}-dev:${GIT_COMMIT} --build-arg ssh_prv_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" -f dockerfile-dev ."
```

And docker file used like below

```
ARG ssh_prv_key

# Authorize SSH Host
# Add the keys and set permissions
RUN mkdir -p /root/.ssh
RUN echo "$ssh_prv_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a similar issue as follow:

**Jenkins pipeline**

```
sh "cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa id_rsa"
sh "docker build -t ${service_name}-dev:${GIT_COMMIT} -f dockerfile-dev ." 
sh "rm id_rsa"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Some instructions...

ADD id_rsa id_rsa

# Now use the "id_rsa" file inside the image...
```

Comment: its getting below error, and already added sh "cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa id_rsa" in jenkins pipeline

Step 5/22 : ADD id_rsa id_rsa &&     chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat &&: file does not exist

Comment: Before offending line try to add a debug command like `RUN ls -la` .